# Gradle Scala plugin - How to specify scala version

Tags: scala, gradle

How can I specify the Scala version in a Gradle Scala project?

The [official documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/2.7/userguide/scala_plugin.html) states that the `scala-library` dependency is used to get hold of the compiler.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.1'
}
```

Does this mean that Scala 2.11.1 will be used?

Comment: Yes it follow the pattern `scope groupId: artifactId: version`. `2.11.1` is version for the artifactId `scala-library`.

Comment: yes, this is how it works

Comment: thanks, seems reasonable.

Comment: could you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the Scala library in the dependencies like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.1'
}
```

Comment: This only declares a direct dependency, transitive dependencies with a different scala-library version may still contaminate it

Comment: @tribbloid How to take care of transitive deps?