# How can i compile java record with scala code?

Tags: java, scala, gradle

I'm currently working on project with both Scala and Java. And we want to rewrite some Scala code on Java. So when I've been starting rewrite my code I've faced with this issue.

```
CountryResponse.java:5: illegal start of type declaration
```

It seem like Scala couldn't compile Java's records introduced in JDK 16. I've made some research and found only [this discussion](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11908) on GitHub. Could someone suggest any workaround to compile Java's records?

I did try increase Scala version from 2.12.2 to 2.13.6 but problem wasn't solved.

We use Java 16, Scala 2.12.2 and Gradle 7.0.1 and also scala and java plugins for Gradle.

Also here my gradle's settings for compile both sources.

```
compileScala {
    sourceCompatibility("16")
    targetCompatibility("16")
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = []
        }
        scala {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/scala', 'src/main/java']
        }
    }
}
```

edit: update link to discussion

Comment: Scala does not compile anything. Your build tool (gradle in this case) compiles your projects which might contain Java, Scala and Kotlin code. This - `CountryResponse.java:5: illegal start of type declaration` has nothing to do with Scala and everything to do with gradle. You need to configure your gradle project correctly to be able to compile Java 16 code.

Comment: Where are your Java source version related configurations? Also, what is the system jdk version ? If it is not Java 16 (or later) then no matter what you do with gradle, jdk just won't be able to compile it. Also, to make your Scala code work under Java 16, the compatible version of Scala is 2.13.5 for Scala 2.13 and 2.12.14 for Scala 2.12.

Comment: @sarveshseri thanks for reply! Yes, you definitely right about compiling... i wasn't clear with this stuff in question, sorry. My another projects work fine with java 16. System jdk is also 16 version. I got error when graldew compileScala runs.

Comment: Why do you have `'src/main/java'` in scala `srcDirs` ? If you are relaying on Gradle Scala plugin to handle Java 16 files as well then you can remove it from java `srcDirs`.

Comment: my code on scala depends on sources from java classes

Comment: Yes, but then you put `'src/main/java'` only in Scala srcDir. Not at both places.

Comment: You right, i was trying to figure out how this setting is affecting workflow and set `/src/main/java/ ` in java srcDir... i edited post and put correct setting

Comment: Are you sure that this build is using Scala 2.13.6 ?

Comment: yes, gradlew uses exactly version from `build.gradle` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44374472/gradle-scala-plugin-how-to-specify-scala-version

Answer (score 4):

I tested with following project containing both Scala and Java 16 sources. The Scala and Java source depends on each other.

If your both Java and Scala sources depend on each other, then you will need to put those sources under common folder. Lets say `main/jvm`.

You can place all your Java `record`s under `main/java`. This will work as long as your `record`s don't have dependency on Scala code. Otherwise you will have to break this into multiple modules and micromanage according to the dependency graph.

Gradle version is 7.1, and this project builds and then runs successfully (both ScalaMain and JavaMain).

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'scala'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

compileScala {
    sourceCompatibility("16")
    targetCompatibility("16")
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
        scala {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/jvm']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.6'
}
```

main/java/TestJavaRecord.java

```java
public record TestJavaRecord(int i) {}
```

main/jvm/TestScalaClass.scala

```scala
class TestScalaClass(val i: Int, val testJavaRecord: TestJavaRecord) {}
```

main/jvm/TestJavaClass.java

```java
public class TestJavaClass {
    public int i;
    public TestScalaClass testScalaClass;

    public TestJavaClass(int i, TestScalaClass testScalaClass) {
        this.i = i;
        this.testScalaClass = testScalaClass;
    }
}
```

main/jvm/ScalaMain.scala

```scala
object ScalaMain extends App {

  val testJavaRecord = new TestJavaRecord(5)

  val testScalaClass = new TestScalaClass(5, testJavaRecord)

  val testJavaClass = new TestJavaClass(5, testScalaClass)

  println(testJavaRecord.i)

  println(testScalaClass.testJavaRecord.i)

  println(testJavaClass.testScalaClass.testJavaRecord.i)

}
```

main/jvm/JavaMain.java

```java
public class JavaMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestJavaRecord testJavaRecord = new TestJavaRecord(5);

        TestScalaClass testScalaClass = new TestScalaClass(5, testJavaRecord);

        TestJavaClass testJavaClass = new TestJavaClass(5, testScalaClass);

        System.out.println(testJavaRecord.i());

        System.out.println(testScalaClass.testJavaRecord().i());

        System.out.println(testJavaClass.testScalaClass.testJavaRecord().i());
    }
}
```

Comment: what if java code also depends on scala code? how i should configure sourceSets?

Comment: Then its a tricky situation. Support for Java 16 `record` was added in https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/9551 but I don't think that any of the release versions contain this yet.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly my case and looks like there is no workaround yet and that sad. Anyway, thank you so much for your help and your time!

Comment: @Zogger Edited for cases where Scala and Java code depend on each other. The only exception being that none of the `record`s can depend on any Scala code.

Comment: That's tricky, i already have all scala code in src/main/scala and java in src/main/java. When i defined java srcSets to `src/main/java` and scala srcSets to `src/main/scala` compiling failed on gradle compileJava because compiler didn't find source of scala classes... I really don't know what's going wrong